# iPhone Facebook SDK Login Problem

Tags: iphone, facebook, sdk, authentication

Hey guys
I just tried to implement the facebook sdk like in the DemoApp from Facebook itself into my application. I basically copied everything from the demoApp but I have a problem when I try to login to facebook.

I press the login button and then the facebook app opens. I authorize myself and press OK. Then I am redirected to my app, but then the `fbDidLogin()` method gets not called. I also defined my app ID in my view controller and the url schema in the info file.

Am I missing something?

Thanks, 
Cheers,
Doonot

Comment: What are you passing into the permissions array?

Are you determining that fbDidLogin got called by looking for NSLog statements?  If not then how?

Have you implemented all of the following handlers (with NSLog statements):
fbDidNotLogin
fbDidLogout

Comment: Yep by checking the logs and I also have a label which should get updated if the login status changes. In initWithNibName I pass this: 

_permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream", @"offline_access",nil] retain]; And yes, the handlers have been implemented aswell! Like in the DemoApp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some trying I figured it out. I used the Interface Builder to set up my Tab Bar Application. I had to change the tab bar application to programmatically in order to have a reference to the view controller which implements the facebook login method:

```
...
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
        settingsController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];  
 ...
```

As Jim mentioned, I forgot to implement the custom url scheme in my app delegate. Thanks to the settingsViewController I simply added:

```
// this method is needed by the facebook login procedure
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [[settingsController facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

That's it, after these changes I can finally login to facebook.

Cheers,
Doonot

Answer (score 0):

`fbDidLogin()` isn't an Objective C method.  Is that the way you have it in the code?

Have you handled your custom URL scheme in your app delegate?

Comment: Damn, I think i missed the part in the app delegate: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
  return [[controller facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
} I basically have a tabBarController in the app delegate class, do I have to set the tabbarcontroller programatically in order to define my view controller for the facebook login page?

Comment: You just need to have your instance of the `Facebook` class accessible to the app delegate or call a method that does.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise? When I try this: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [[tabBarController facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}
Then the app crashes which is kind of obvious. But that tabBarController is the only controller which is currently available in the app delegate class..

Comment: The sample app's view controller creates an instance of the `Facebook` class.  When you application is called from Facebook's app with a custom URL, your app delegate is sent the `handleOpenURL:` message.  At that point, your app delegate needs to pass the information it has received on to the instance of the Facebook class.  It does this by asking the view controller for a reference to it with `controller facebook`.  As that view controller has a `facebook` property defined, this works.

Comment: A standard tab bar controller doesn't create an instance of the `Facebook` class and doesn't have a `facebook` property, so obviously just substituting the tab bar controller for the sample app's view controller isn't going to work.  But if you've copied and pasted the sample code, then you're instantiating it *somewhere*.  All you have to do is get your app delegate a reference to it.

Comment: Yep I have a SettingsViewController which instanciates the Facebook Class: _facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId]; Now this is done in the viewDidLoad() method of SettingsViewController. Now how can I give the app delegate a reference to it? :) thx man

Comment: That really depends on the architecture of your app.  `viewDidLoad` may not even be the correct place to instantiate `Facebook`.  It depends on a whole range of factors.  I recommend [the View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/) to give you the knowledge necessary to figure these things out.  And again, `viewDidLoad()` is not Objective C.

Comment: You know I put it there because the guys of Facebook did so. I think my knowledge of view controllers is enough for the moment. I didn't find any tutorial that explains how to use it in a tab bar application. In the end the facebook session should be accessible everywhere in the app. Anyway, thanks, although I don't have a solution.

Comment: The guys of Facebook have a different application architecture to you.  What makes sense for them to do does not necessary make sense for you to do.  If you are looking for tutorials to do exactly what the Facebook sample app does except with a different architecture, then you really do need to learn more about how view controllers are managed.  This is a fundamental part of iOS development, you can't expect to skip over it and not hit a brick wall.